# How to detach a web service application already deployed from a specific port?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, endpoint

Hi I deployed a SOAP based Web Service application **CalculatorRpcWSImpl** using JAX-WS API in a specific port says **7892** using `Endpoint.publish(url, object)` method.

But Now I want to undeploy/detach this Web service **CalculatorRpcWSImpl** from that specific port **7892**. How can I do that?

**Publisher class**

```
public class CalculatoRpcWSPublisher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CalculatorRpcWS crw = new CalculatorRpcWSImpl();
    String url = "http://localhost:7892/ws/rpccalculator";

    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish(url, crw);

    if(endpoint.isPublished()){
        System.out.println("CalculatoRpcWS web services successfully deployed in server.");
    }else{
        endpoint.stop();
        System.out.println("Some error occur to deploye CalculatoRpcWS web services.");
    }
}
```

**WSDL XML File of CalculatorRpcWS Web Service:**

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://rpc.jaxws.ws.sayan.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://rpc.jaxws.ws.sayan.com/" name="CalculatoRpcWSImplService">
<types/>
<message name="add">
<part name="arg0" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="arg1" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="addResponse">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="CalculatoRpcWS">
<operation name="add" parameterOrder="arg0 arg1">
<input wsam:Action="http://rpc.jaxws.ws.sayan.com/CalculatoRpcWS/addRequest" message="tns:add"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://rpc.jaxws.ws.sayan.com/CalculatoRpcWS/addResponse" message="tns:addResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="CalculatoRpcWSImplPortBinding" type="tns:CalculatoRpcWS">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
<operation name="add">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://rpc.jaxws.ws.sayan.com/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://rpc.jaxws.ws.sayan.com/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="CalculatoRpcWSImplService">
<port name="CalculatoRpcWSImplPort" binding="tns:CalculatoRpcWSImplPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:7892/ws/rpccalculator"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: You already use the method endpoint.stop() to stop the endpoint from being published. What is not working with it?

Comment: Stop the service?

Comment: When I first time compile and run the Publisher class it's deployed that Web Service on 7892 port. But again when I want to publish another Web service on that same port it's showing some runtime error "Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind".
That's why I want to detach/undeploy the old web services from that port and want to publish a new web service application on same port 7892.

Comment: @SusannahPotts Not stop the service. I want to free that Port(7892) means undeploy/detach CalculatorRpcWS Web Service as I can use that port(7892) to publish another Web Service or do other work on that port.

Comment: Yeah, and to undeploy and put another service there, you would need to stop the service.  Then move it to a new port.